# How can I get back from an un-typed Expression to a typed one?

Tags: c#, linq, casting, type-conversion, expression

I just ran into a problem involving [Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.aspx).

In my `class<T>` have a field

```
Dictionary<Expression, ProjectedCollection> mCache;
```

where both `Expression` and `ProjectedCollection` cannot be specified as `Expression<T, S>` and `ProjectedCollection<S>` because the `S` will be different things at runtime:

```
void AddSomething<S>(Expression<Func<T, S>> projection)
{
  if (!mCache.ContainsKey(projection))
  {
    var runnable = projection.Compile();
    var allProjected = from elm in mList
                       select runnable(elm);

    mCache.Add(projection, new ProjectedCollection<S>(allProjected));
  }
}
```

---

Now at some point where I don't know `S`, I want to iterate over everything in my cache and apply the expression to a new thing.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<Expression, ProjectedCollection> keyValuePair in mCache)
{
  // Want something like
  var func = keyValuePair.Key.Compile();
  keyValuePair.Value.SignalAdd(func(newThing));
}
```

But the [Compile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345362) method is not available for the un-typed `Expression`. And casting is also not possible without knowing `S`.

Does anybody have an idea how to tackle this?

Comment: There's a problem with your approach... `Expression` doesn't override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, so using it as a dictionary key won't work. Two identical expressions won't be considered equal...

Comment: BTW, the `Compile` method is available in `LambdaExpression`, which is the base class of `Expression<TDelegate>`. But it returns an untyped delegate...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: That's solved by a custom `IEqualityComparer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast to a `LambdaExpression` and call Compile on it. It will return an untyped delegate. You can...

- ...cast this delegate to one of the Func/Action types
- ...inspect its structure using reflection
- ...use Delegate.DynamicInvoke to call it

Comment: Casting the delegate is also not possible for lack of `S`. But casting to `LambdaExpression` in combination with `DynamicInvoke` did the job. Thanks!